# Magento 2 Admin panel configration migration

Tags: magento2, configuration, admin-panel, migration

How can we migrate Magento 2 Admin panel configurations from one magento 2 project to another.

Lets say we did some configuration in DEV server and when you setup UAT server you will need to do the same configurations manually again. So i am looking to automate this process.

If i can get some way to extract the configurations of one server and updated the same in another.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this table `core_config_data` table which has all settings related to admin configurations.

> Export this table contains admin configuration from your DEV instance
>   db and import in to your required environment.

Clear cache once you migrate the dump

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

Export `core_config_data` table from the DEV server and import it in the new UAT server.

And if you change your domain then change secure and unsecure base URL.

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean`

And check that all configurations are set in UAT server.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for your feedback.

I tried with another way to export the admin panel configurations and import them. It basically exports all or only the required configurations in **app/etc/config.php** and **app/etc/env.php** file.

We can then replace the config.php file to our other Magento instance and run the commands to import it.

See this link for [Magento 2 export admin panel configurations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-export.html)

However, after importing the configurations in my second instance, I was not able to edit the configurations from the Default store. Either I need to be on the Main website or other store views.

thanks